# Translating YUI to jQuery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

I am totally new to jquery and I need to migrate some code from YUI to jquery.
Need some help to start off with this.Please help translating the following piece of YUI code to jquery.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    var o = objs[i];
    (function(obj, args, type, fn) {
        YAHOO.util.Event.on(obj, type, function() {
            fn.run(obj, args)
        });
    })(o.obj, o.args, this._type, this);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This inner part of you code:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.on(obj, type, function() {
   fn.run(obj, args)
});
```

should most likely be replaced with:

```
$(obj).bind(type, function() {
    fn.run(obj, args);
});
```

But the code largely depends on the data supplied as `obj` and `type`. You should read [this jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) about event types.